# Ethernet says it's connected but can't access internet. But i can access internet after 15-30 minutes . why i face this problem?

Tags: 14.04, networking, dual-boot, internet, ethernet

I am using ubuntu and windows 10 by dual boot. when i boot ubuntu Ethernet says it's connected but can't access internet. But i can access internet after 15-30 minutes if in this time i don't touch my pc. why this problem?

**SYSLOG**

```
Jul 17 10:56:40 ninja-desktop ModemManager[4043]: <warn>  Couldn't find support for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:02:00.0': not supported by any plugin
Jul 17 10:56:40 ninja-desktop NetworkManager[4050]: <info> (eth0): carrier now ON (device state 20)
Jul 17 10:56:40 ninja-desktop NetworkManager[4050]: <info> (eth0): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed') [20 30 40]
Jul 17 10:56:40 ninja-desktop kernel: [ 3384.440789] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: link up
Jul 17 10:56:40 ninja-desktop kernel: [ 3384.440803] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Jul 17 10:56:40 ninja-desktop NetworkManager[4050]: <info> Auto-activating connection 'Connect'.
Jul 17 10:56:40 ninja-desktop NetworkManager[4050]: <info> Activation (eth0) starting connection 'Connect'
Jul 17 10:56:40 ninja-desktop NetworkManager[4050]: <info> (eth0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Jul 17 10:56:40 ninja-desktop NetworkManager[4050]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jul 17 10:56:40 ninja-desktop NetworkManager[4050]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Jul 17 10:56:40 ninja-desktop NetworkManager[4050]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Jul 17 10:56:40 ninja-desktop NetworkManager[4050]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Jul 17 10:56:40 ninja-desktop NetworkManager[4050]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Jul 17 10:56:40 ninja-desktop NetworkManager[4050]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Jul 17 10:56:40 ninja-desktop NetworkManager[4050]: <info> (eth0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jul 17 10:56:40 ninja-desktop NetworkManager[4050]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
Jul 17 10:56:40 ninja-desktop NetworkManager[4050]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Jul 17 10:56:40 ninja-desktop NetworkManager[4050]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Jul 17 10:56:40 ninja-desktop NetworkManager[4050]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Jul 17 10:56:40 ninja-desktop NetworkManager[4050]: <info> (eth0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Jul 17 10:56:40 ninja-desktop NetworkManager[4050]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Commit) scheduled...
Jul 17 10:56:40 ninja-desktop NetworkManager[4050]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Jul 17 10:56:40 ninja-desktop NetworkManager[4050]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) started...
Jul 17 10:56:40 ninja-desktop avahi-daemon[593]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 10.0.0.4.
Jul 17 10:56:40 ninja-desktop avahi-daemon[593]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jul 17 10:56:40 ninja-desktop avahi-daemon[593]: Registering new address record for 10.0.0.4 on eth0.IPv4.
Jul 17 10:56:41 ninja-desktop NetworkManager[4050]: <info> (eth0): device state change: ip-config -> secondaries (reason 'none') [70 90 0]
Jul 17 10:56:41 ninja-desktop NetworkManager[4050]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) complete.
Jul 17 10:56:41 ninja-desktop NetworkManager[4050]: <info> (eth0): device state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Jul 17 10:56:41 ninja-desktop NetworkManager[4050]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Jul 17 10:56:41 ninja-desktop NetworkManager[4050]: <info> Policy set 'Connect' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Jul 17 10:56:41 ninja-desktop NetworkManager[4050]: nm_dns_plugin_child_spawn: assertion 'argv[0] != NULL' failed
Jul 17 10:56:41 ninja-desktop NetworkManager[4050]: <warn> DNS: plugin dnsmasq update failed
Jul 17 10:56:41 ninja-desktop NetworkManager[4050]: <info> Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Jul 17 10:56:41 ninja-desktop avahi-daemon[593]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::eea8:6bff:fe70:9564.
Jul 17 10:56:41 ninja-desktop avahi-daemon[593]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jul 17 10:56:41 ninja-desktop avahi-daemon[593]: Registering new address record for fe80::eea8:6bff:fe70:9564 on eth0.*.
Jul 17 10:56:53 ninja-desktop NetworkManager[4050]: <info> Activation (eth0) successful, device activated.
Jul 17 10:56:53 ninja-desktop dbus[453]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using servicehelper)
Jul 17 10:56:53 ninja-desktop NetworkManager[4050]: <info> WiFi hardware radio set enabled
Jul 17 10:56:53 ninja-desktop dbus[453]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jul 17 10:57:33 ninja-desktop ntpdate[4136]: Can't find host ntp.ubuntu.com: Name or service not known (-2)
Jul 17 10:57:33 ninja-desktop ntpdate[4136]: no servers can be used, exiting
Jul 17 11:00:10 ninja-desktop kernel: [ 3594.937552] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
Jul 17 11:00:10 ninja-desktop kernel: [ 3595.032704] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1307, idProduct=0163
Jul 17 11:00:10 ninja-desktop kernel: [ 3595.032710] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jul 17 11:00:10 ninja-desktop kernel: [ 3595.032712] usb 1-1.3: Product: USB Flash Drive
Jul 17 11:00:10 ninja-desktop kernel: [ 3595.032714] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: USB 2.0
Jul 17 11:00:10 ninja-desktop kernel: [ 3595.032716] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 97d4e5f6b2639d
Jul 17 11:00:10 ninja-desktop mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 5: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3"
Jul 17 11:00:10 ninja-desktop mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 5 was not an MTP device
Jul 17 11:00:10 ninja-desktop kernel: [ 3595.046300] usb-storage 1-1.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Jul 17 11:00:10 ninja-desktop kernel: [ 3595.046463] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-1.3:1.0
Jul 17 11:00:10 ninja-desktop kernel: [ 3595.046582] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
Jul 17 11:00:10 ninja-desktop kernel: [ 3595.049512] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
Jul 17 11:00:11 ninja-desktop kernel: [ 3596.046862] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     USB 2.0  USB Flash Drive  0.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Jul 17 11:00:11 ninja-desktop kernel: [ 3596.047245] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
:
```

Comment: This is rather odd. Please provide logs from `/var/log/syslog` and output of `dmesg`

Comment: I have provided syslog Please check

Comment: Is this syslog excerpt from when it works or right after the boot finishes?

Comment: This syslog after works

Comment: Can you provide some network manager entries from the time where internet is not available?

Comment: Please check this [syslog from not available](http://paste.ubuntu.com/19751551/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42607/discussion-between-riyad-and-phillip-zyan-k-lee-stockmann).

Answer (score 1):

In your log I see that ipv6 is configured too

```
Jul 17 10:56:41 ninja-desktop avahi-daemon[593]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::eea8:6bff:fe70:9564.
Jul 17 10:56:41 ninja-desktop avahi-daemon[593]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jul 17 10:56:41 ninja-desktop avahi-daemon[593]: Registering new address record for fe80::eea8:6bff:fe70:9564 on eth0.*.
```

Can you modify ipv6 settings on network card to Method: Ignore and see if it works ?

[image]

One other thing too check is dnsmasq. Can you check if dnsmasq is installed and remove it.

Use following command

```
sudo apt-get remove dnsmasq
```

I found this solution on [ubuntuforums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2193214).

Comment: @Riyad - does this solve your problem? From what I see, the ipv6-stuff would be my best guess, too.

Comment: Sometimes work sometimes not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the DNS settings of your network.
Go to Network--> Settings--> IPV4 Settings-->Additional DNS Settings
add the DNS address provided by your service provider, restart the browser and check.

Comment: All network settings properly provided. I am using internet by this settings. My problem is when i shutdown my pc then again open my pc ethernet says it's connected but can't access internet. BUT if after ubuntu open i don't use ubuntu for 15-30 minutes then internet working.